# How to approach this integration problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been auditing a calculus class where the current topic is integration. Recently, the teacher set a type of problem that is new to me:

[image: Calculus 2 - Spring 2016 - Dr. (redacted). Quiz 6. Directions: No Talking. No books or notes. To receive maximal credit, show all your work. 1) Draw a cute bunny.]

What is this??

Comment: As you might expect, we have no idea.

Comment: It looks to me as though the quiz was given as free points to anyone who bothered to show up to the quiz date and has no questions related to mathematics on it.  The question merely asks the student to draw a cute bunny, which should require (*almost*) no mathematical skill whatsoever, and will likely be graded solely based on completion.

Comment: Define "draw", "cute", and "bunny". Sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: @Nehorai: Tell that to my teacher!

Comment: I haven't a clue why anyone would downvote this. The question is useful and clear!

Comment: Awesome question (+1)

Comment: Drawing a rabbit is quite hard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try  to draw this cute bunny:

$\quad$

[image]

Comment: Oh wow! That is a cute bunny!